# How to deal with variable const in templated code?

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I have a class `myClass` that is templated, and I have it in mind to use it for two particular types.

The trouble is that whether or not something should be `const` in `myClass` depends on whether it is instantiated with the first type (in which pretty much everything is `const`) or the second type (in which pretty much everything is non-const).

How do I solve this problem? It seems there are two possible approaches.

I could write `const` in the templated code as if it were for the first type (the one that actually is const), and then somehow "throw away" all those consts once I instantiate with the second type? Is this possible?

The second approach is to not write const at all, and then when I instantiate `myClass` with the first type, I make the entire object itself `const`. This seems to make up a bit for the lack of const-correctness in the class implementation itself...

Or maybe I can do something else?

EDIT: Wait, no, the last approach wouldn't work, as I then wouldn't be able to call non-const methods....

Comment: Please show us the actual class.

Comment: you may want to take a look at [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) and [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). To get a more concrete answer, please consider to add a [mcve]

Comment: I'd also add [std::is_const](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const)

Comment: though I would recommend to reconsider if having an implementation with `const` and one without for two different types is really best realized as a template

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have these two arbitrary types you want to instantiate your template class with, the first of which should trigger `const`ness for your members:

```
struct RequiresConst
{};

struct OtherStruct
{};
```

You can then write some convenience templates like this:

```
template<class T, bool B>
using conditional_const = typename std::conditional<B, const T, T>::type;

template<class T>
constexpr bool needsConst = std::is_same_v<T, RequiresConst>;
```

This allows you to naturally spell out what you want:

```
template<class T>
struct MyClass
{
    conditional_const<int, needsConst<T>> member;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rcpvLn) (including test).

Note that this only works for member variables. I'm not aware of a way to make functions `const` or non-`const` in a similarly convenient way. But you could write a const and non-const version for each function and enable exactly one of each pair via `std::enable_if` (or some other SFINAE).

It should also be mentioned that "this member should be const if the template parameter is *this* exact class" is a pretty odd requirement - not necessarily wrong but smelly. There is probably some specific trait *that* class has that you should check instead. But maybe your use case really only ever has the template instantiated for those two classes and the above will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use a type_traits class.

Start with an empty typetraits class, then specialize it for your first type. Place there all the types you need with the const.

Then specialize it again for your second type, and place there the types without const.

Finally, in your templated class, use the type traits with the template type to select the types you need.